# Filter text with Python before tweeting

Tags: python, filter, automation

Still kinda new to this stuff so please, bear with me:

I have a java program that scrapes for links, works like a charm. I also recently learned how to make an auto tweeting bot in python, also works flawlessly.

Now here comes where i am having troubles...

The java program exports all links found in a text file (no biggie) and my twitter bot grabs any lines in the text file and tweets them (again, no biggie). BUT what i want to do is filter the twitter bot to ONLY tweet specific links that have specific key words...

Here is my twitter bot

```
    import tweepy, time, sys

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])


CONSUMER_KEY = 'example'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'example'
ACCESS_KEY = 'example'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'example'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

for line in f:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(60)#Tweet every 60 seconds
```

Now i have tried multiple things like

```
for line in f:
    if: 'robot' in line:
        api.update_status(line)
        time.sleep(60)#Tweet every 60 seconds
```

Which doesn't seem to be working. I am curious if i have to use configparser to filter the data?

Comment: You don't need configparser to filter the data. But your examples have multiple syntax errors, partly, but not all depending on indentation. Please correct that, by copying in the real code e.g. `if 'robots' in line` correctly. Also give the output that you get with filtered links, why would you wait 60 seconds in rewriting a file? Give a sample of the input data. Do all of that by updating your post, and while your at it, remove thanks and appreciation lines.

Comment: I did update the post with the correct code. I write in Sublime so maybe its being buggy and messing up indentation, or I am by using Ctrl K? Cause it runs perfectly on my end. And I am getting no output with any filters on thats the issue. 

All I am getting is an error not allowing the tweet because the first line in the file has already been tweeted. Thats how I am testing to see if the filters are working and they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to use the if loop syntax correctly;

`if 'word' in line :
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(60)`

Secondly , to make it as a kind of 'shortcut' you could do it like this:

```
if 'word' or 'word' or 'word' in line:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(60)
```

ps:- you could write as many words to filter as you wish